# SVG reuse a group but change fill color

Tags: svg

So I have a `<g>` element with some `<rect>s` inside it, they all have same fill color, but can be of different sizes. I want to reuse the `<g>`, but fill it with a different color, is it possible?

I can change the markup any way I like.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can define the rect group using `<defs>` like so:

```
<defs>
    <g id="rect-group">
        <rect x="0" y="0" width="60" height="30"/>
        <rect x="20" y="10" width="20" height="50"/>
    </g>
</defs>
```

Then you can use this group multiple times, putting it in different places with with `transform` if you like:

```
<g class="group-1" transform="translate(10.5,20.5)">
    <use xlink:href="#rect-group" />
</g>

<g class="group-2" transform="translate(55.5,32.5)">
    <use xlink:href="#rect-group" />
</g>
```

You can style these groups directly or give them different classes as above and use CSS to style as you like:

```
  <style> 
    .group-1{
        fill: red;
        stroke: white;
    }
    .group-2{
        fill: blue;
        stroke: black;
    }
  </style>
```

For an example, see: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/169269/rect_group.svg

Comment: Thanks! Works like a charm! And could you tell why you are using transform and not x/y?

Comment: I don't think you can add x/y to a group, can you? Using transform means you can put the groups in different places and also do things like transform="rotate(45)" if you want to rotate the groups.

Comment: OK, I didn't know that. You can do that if you prefer.

Comment: Unfortunately the styles don't apply to the start/middle/end markers.